# Running jQuery code on dynamically created tags

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of tags which are created by a php script. This php script is ran periodically as shown below and the php file order.php returns the required HTML

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("foo").load("order.php");
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("foo").load('order.php?randval='+ Math.random());
  }, 100000);
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

This all works as expected and using firebug I can see the following HTML has been created:

```
<foo>
  <bar>something</bar>
  <bar>something else</bar>
  <bar>another thing</bar>
</foo>
```

Now I want to be able to perform a php action when a div is clicked on. I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("bar").click(function() {
    alert("Hello, World");
  });
});
```

Nothing happens. However if I manually type in a bar tag into any part of the HTML, the alert with Hello World appears.

Is it possible for bar tags created by the php script to act in the same way as one that is manually typed into the HTML?

Comment: it should be. PHP generated elements are generated serverside and then added to the DOM when the page loads. They should be accessible via JS so long as the JS is executed after the page has finished loading. Meaning it's wrapped in a document.ready or $(function{}) if your using JQuery.

Comment: @TheSnooker Have a look at the code posted.  It uses `.load`

Comment: your click event to $("bar").click(function() is wroong it sound be to eith #bar or .bar depending if its a class or id.  simply 'ba r on its own wont do anything'

Comment: @SubstanceD Actually with the posted (fake) html, the elements are `<foo>` and `<bar>`... obviously made up example, but the selectors match the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the event to an ancestor of `bar` which isn't dynamically added to the page:

```
$('foo').on('click', 'bar', function() {
    alert("Hello, World");
});
```

Comment: Yes forgot about that. Adding things to the DOM requires .live or .on to access. I think that .live is also deprecated too

Comment: James you've managed to copy the question mistake the selector foo needs . or #  =D

Comment: @SubstanceD `#` matches and ID and `.` matches a class. To match an element you just use the name of the element. `<div id=myId class=myClass>` can be matched with `$('#myId')`, `$('.myClass')` or simply `$('div')`. http://api.jquery.com/element-selector. In the question, `foo` and `bar` are element names, not IDs or classes.

Comment: Hi James. This is exactly the advice I needed and it now works. Thanks for your quick response.